# Why a poll event loop slows down my program?

Tags: c++, sfml

So, I'm trying to make a 2d platform game for a university project, and I wanted to have textfields on a settings menu to set the keybinds needed for the game using the TextEntered event. When I tried the TextField class on a separated main everything works perfectly, but when I tried to put it in the Settings class, the text is recognized very slowly (even after few seconds after I pressed a certain key). Is there a method to handle events inside a class which is different from the class containing the main loop without slowing down everything? This is the poll event loop to check for entered text in the Settings class:

```cpp
sf::Event event{};

while (window->pollEvent(event)) {
    for (auto &t : textFields) {
        if (t.second->contains(mousePos)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered) {
                if (event.text.unicode < 128) {
                    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space))
                        t.second->addString("Space");
                    else {
                        // Convert to uppercase
                        sf::String string =
                            static_cast<sf::String>(event.text.unicode);
                        std::transform(string.begin(), string.end(),
                                       string.begin(), ::toupper);
                        t.second->addString(string);
                    }

                    t.second->setString();
                }
            }

            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::BackSpace)) {
                t.second->clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing to do is to review your code structure. It is very inefficient, as it is. Well, it would be for large amount of text fields:

```
while (window->pollEvent(event)) { // for each event
    for (auto &t : textFields) { // for each text field
        if (t.second->contains(mousePos)) { // check position
            if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered) { // is it a text entered event
```

This will have you check a bunch of position, for each text field, whenever there's an event, even if it's not the right type.

At the very minimum, you need to change it to:

```
while (window->pollEvent(event)) { // for each event
    if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered) { // is it a text entered event
        for (auto &t : textFields) { // for each text field
            if (t.second->contains(mousePos)) { // check position
```

Then, you only iterate over the text fields when you have a text entered event.